# PHP 7 Zend Framework 2 Getting the Zend Framework Version

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Please help with the right documentation for PHP Zend Framework 2. There are two documentations as in the following URLs:

https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/modules.html

https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/modules/

There are discrepancies viz.

Docs:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Application\\": "module/Application/src/",
        "Album\\": "module/Album/src/"
    }
},

zf-tutorial/
    /module
        /Album
            /config
            /src
                /Controller
                /Form
                /Model
            /view
                /album
                    /album
```

Manual:

```
"autoload": {
     "psr-0": { "Album": "module/Album/src/" }
},

zf2-tutorial/
    /module
        /Album
            /config
            /src
                /Album
                    /Controller
                    /Form
                    /Model
            /view
                 /album
                    /album
```

Which doc especially the code is the suitable for PHP 7 and Zend Framework 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The http://docs.zendframework.com link will always hold docs for the latest version, which is Zend Framework 3. If you specifically want ZF2, then use the first URL, which is for ZF2.4 (you can see the version number in the URL).